# Is it possible to install ROSBRIDGE on Gentoo?

Tags: ros, gentoo, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, i am looking for a possibility to install Rosbridge on Gentoo. Do you know maybe the easiest way to do this?

Is there any possibility to emerge any ros-rosbridge package? Or there is just the only way ... download files from
https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite

Thanks a lot for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193725/is-it-possible-to-install-rosbridge-on-gentoo?/) by [Maksym Figat](https://answers.ros.org/users/20338/maksym-figat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For Gentoo you will probably want to follow the source installation instructions: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1